# Domain of definition of the function

Tags: functions, logarithms, relations

I was going through some questions of **Relations and Functions** and now I am stuck to one. Question says

> **Question**: Domain of definition of the function 
>   $$f(x)=\frac{9}{9-x^2}+\log_{10}(x^3-x)$$
>   is?

Till yet I know that the denominator of first term (i.e. $\frac{9}{9-x^2}$) will be non-zero. So I figured,

$$9-x^2\ne0$$
$$\implies x\ne\pm3$$

And from second term (i.e. $\log_{10}x^3-x$), we know that the term inside the logarithm can never be less than or equal to zero. So,

$$\log_{10}(x^3-x)$$
$$\implies x^3-x>0$$
$$\implies (x-1)x(x+1)>0$$

From here I know that if $x−1$ is negative when $x<1$ and positive when $x>1$. $x+1$ is negative when $x<−1$ and positive when $x>−1$. But I am still not getting the domain in a **specific interval**.

I seriously need help in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x-1$ is negative when $x<1$ and positive when $x>1$.  $x+1$ is negative when $x<-1$ and positive when $x>-1$.  Using this and the fact that the product of two negative numbers is positive and a negative times a positive is negative, you can find all $x$ such that $(x-1)x(x+1)>0$.

Comment: Then what can be the domain of the function. I want it to be in kind of intervals like $(i,j)\cup(k,l)$. Like this.

Comment: Perhaps you can work with a few separate intervals, and then the intersect of these sets should be a solution for your problem.

Comment: The intervals you want to look at are $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,\infty)$.  Different combinations of the factors will be positive or negative depending on which interval you are in, because of what I wrote in my "Answer".